# Appending a list that tallies the length of words

Tags: python, list, append

I am taking words from a text file, stripping each word of \n and creating a new list out of these words.

Now I need to go through systematically word by word finding the length of the word, then adding 1 to a tally of that word length i.e. I would start off with an empty tally:

`length_of_words = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

then if the list of stripped words contained 5x 7 letter words and 3x 2 letter words I would end up with:

`length_of_words = [0,3,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

What this boils down to is:

- Calculate the length of a word e.g. n
- Add one to length_of_words for length_of_words[n-1] (as it still starts with 1 letter words being the 0th item)

I am really stuck on how to essentially increase the value of 1 item in a list by 1, instead of just appending 1 to the end of the list.

What I have at the moment is this:

```
lines = open ('E:\Python\Assessment\dracula.txt', 'r'). readlines ()

stripped_list = [item.strip() for item in lines]

tally = [] #empty set of lengths
for lengths in range(1,20):
    tally.append(0)

print tally #original tally

for i in stripped_list:
    length_word = int(len(i))
    tally[length_word] = tally[length_word] + 1
print tally
```

Comment: The first and most important question is what language are you using?

Comment: Damn, Python, I don't know why I removed it from the title, sorry, let me update the question

Comment: Just use the `python` tag instead - you don't need to add "Python" to your question's title.

Comment: What is not working correctly about your code?

Comment: @eldarerathis the python tag was already there but it wasn't very clear.

Comment: @BenH it is saying 'list index out of range'

Comment: Your question as originally written was tagged with `list`, `append` and `length`. It didn't have the `python` tag until I added it, but it's immaterial now.

Comment: tally has length 19, so if `int(len(i))` is ever greater than 18, the index will be out of range.

Comment: The tally code looks fine.  The stripped_list part looks suspect though (depending on what the input file looks like).  If there is more than one word per line, you would need to remove the punctuation, and split the line into individual words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the wrong line in your code was `tally[length_word]`, you forgot to add `- 1`

I've also made some changes to your code to make it more [pythonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29#Name_and_neologisms)

```
#lines = open ('E:\Python\Assessment\dracula.txt', 'r'). readlines ()

#stripped_list = [item.strip() for item in lines]

with open('/home/facundo/tmp/words.txt') as i:
    stripped_list = [x.strip() for x in i.readlines()]

#tally = [] #empty set of lengths
#for lengths in range(1,20):
#    tally.append(0)

tally = [0] * 20

print tally #original tally

for i in stripped_list:
    #length_word = int(len(i))
    word_length = len(i)
    #tally[length_word] = tally[length_word] + 1
    if word_length > 0:
        tally[word_length - 1] += 1

print tally
```

Comment: Good answer thanks! But one question, using tally = [0] * 20 renders the previous definition of tally useless doesn't it? Thanks again.

Comment: yes, that's why I commented out those lines, it's just easier to do it that way

Comment: "The previous definition of tally" has been explicitly commented out here. This is a technique used on forums to say "the code I've added here is a simpler (or more idiomatic), drop-in replacement for the code I've commented out".

Answer (score 2):

The [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class is helpful for that sort of thing:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> words = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'.split()
>>> Counter(map(len, words))
Counter({3: 4, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 1})
```

The code you've posted in your question works fine as-is, so I'm not sure where you're stuck.

FWIW, here are some minor code improvements (more Pythonic style):

```
stripped_list = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'.split()

tally = [0] * 20
print tally #original tally

for i in stripped_list:
    length_word = len(i)
    tally[length_word] += 1
print tally
```